# Why can't I remove the first item of an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

There is a container `ul` that stays at a set height so when the content inside the `ul` overflows, it should remove the first item from the list. Each list item is shown as a search result and the `ul` can only hold 6 results without overflowing. The list is meant to be changed using `setRecent` as it was declared using `useState`, but when I try to change the list by removing the first item using `[...list].splice(1)`, it returns this error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

When I remove the `setRecent` and just return the value `[...list].splice(1)` it returns the list without the first item as it should, however the `setRecent` is needed to change the value of the list.

How do I fix this?

```js
const [recent, setRecent] = useState(["Dubai", "Paris", "London", "paris", "new york", "dubai", "New York"]);

const InsideSection = () => {
  const ulRef = createRef();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (onSearch) {
      const element = ulRef.current;
      
      if (element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight) { // checks for overflow
        console.log("overflow");
        console.log(recent, "before"); // returns [] instead of the list 
        console.log([...recent].slice(1)); 
        // this should return ["Paris", "London", "paris", "new york", "dubai", "New York"] (without the first "Dubai") 
        // but when there is a setRecent inside the if statement, it causes an error as recent is []
        setRecent([...recent].slice(1)); // causes the error
        console.log(recent, "after"); // returns []
      }
    }
  }, [ulRef]);

  if (onSearch) {
    return (
      <div className = "search-container" >
          ...
          <ul ref = {ulRef} >
              <RecentSearches />
          </ul> 
      </div >
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Most likely you have to pass `recent` as a dependency to useLayoutEffect (because it will only update the callback inside useLayoutEffect, if the dependency changes)

Comment: @F.Müller - In this specific case, I think they *don't* want `recent` to be a dependency (but they will definitely need to use the callback form of state setter in that case).

Comment: I don't think you can do this *just* with a layout effect, because resize is a thing (but won't trigger a layout effect). You'll need a combination of effect or layout effect (with a callback state setter) and a resize handler. Before doing it that way, though, I'd look for CSS alternatives instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is correct - You can get rid of the immediate problem of seeing a stale `recent` if you change the `setRecent` line to `setRecent(recent => recent.slice(1))` but it's still not going to do what you're wanting. The layout referred to in the name of this hook is not related to changes in the window layout :-(

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agreed, unless you do some kind of debouncing. I found a solution with a ref and a setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is defining your InsideSection component inside the parent component. When from the InsideSection you call the setRecent state handler of the parent, you are causing a re-rendering which causes the parent component to be executed again and your InsideSection component to be re-created.
This triggers your useLayoutEffect once more, the useLayoutEffect re-update the state of the parent which re-renders and re-create the InsideSection which re-triggers useLayoutEffect again and again.

Each time, it slices your recent array from ["Dubai", "Paris", "London", "paris", "new york", "dubai", "New York"] to ["Paris", "London", "paris", "new york", "dubai", "New York"] to ["London", "paris", "new york", "dubai", "New York"] and so on until it is [] and cannot be sliced more (this is where it throws an error).

The solution is to move the InsideSection component out of the parent and, if the recent variable is only used by the InsideSection component, define it there and not in the parent.
If the recent variable needs to be used by both, parent and child, then a "less" clean solution is to pass it as a prop.

The possible solution looks like this:

```
const InsideSection = (props) => {
  const { onSearch, recent, setRecent } = props;
  const ulRef = createRef();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (onSearch) {
      const element = ulRef.current;
      
      if (element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight) {
        setRecent([...recent].slice(1));
      }
    }
  }, [ulRef]);

  if (onSearch) {
    return (
      <div className = "search-container" >
          ...
          <ul ref = {ulRef} >
              <RecentSearches />
          </ul> 
      </div >
    );
  }

  return <></>;
}

const Parent = () => {
  const onSearch = true; // Dunno where it comes from
  const [recent, setRecent] = useState(["Dubai", "Paris", "London", "paris", "new york", "dubai", "New York"]);

  return (
    <InnerSection onSearch={onSearch} recent={recent} setRecent={setRecent} />
  );
}
```

The other solution is to use Context, I leave you the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

PS: The code might need some adjustment, it is just an example

EDIT: Gist containing a complete example: https://gist.github.com/ThomasSquall/cdbea86f1204d8e4c0b627aacc92c02f

Comment: The explanation makes sense but the solution didn't work and I am still unsure of how to fix the problem

Comment: The recent variable is needed outside the function so it cannot be declared inside the function

Comment: @tices I wrote this piece of code based on the solution I provided and it works fine for me: https://gist.github.com/ThomasSquall/cdbea86f1204d8e4c0b627aacc92c02f

Comment: @tices I just noticed you are using Javascript and not Typescript so I removed the type declarations from my answer, this could be the reason it wasn't working for you

Comment: `recent` is used in other places inside the main function so would changing it outside the component using props actually change its value? Because moving the `InsideSection` component out of the main function means that the `RecentSearches` component also needs to be moved out of the main function, and this function changes the values of multiple `useState` variables that are declared and used in different places in the main function so it would not work properly if the values were not changed

Comment: @tices as long as you pass the state handler (setRecent), yes, it will work. Again, I strongly suggest using context in case the app is getting more complex than this

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect, but it kinda works if you use a debouncing strategy with a ref and a timeout:

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-gould-4bmhns?file=/src/App.js

[image: screenshot-solution]

```
import { createRef, useLayoutEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [recent, setRecent] = useState([
    "Dubai",
    "Paris",
    "London",
    "paris",
    "new york",
    "dubai",
    "New York"
  ]);
  const [updatedRecent, setUpdatedRecent] = useState();
  const onSearch = true;
  const ulRef = createRef();
  let timeoutId = useRef();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("> debounced", updatedRecent);
    setRecent(() => updatedRecent);
    timeoutId.current = null;
  }, [updatedRecent]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (onSearch) {
      const element = ulRef.current;
      if (element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight) {
        if (!timeoutId.current) {
          timeoutId.current = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("update");
            setUpdatedRecent(() => [...recent].slice(1));
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }, [onSearch, ulRef, recent, timeoutId]);
// [...]
```